# Importing a JSON from API into CSV is importing as a single row with all the data points as an individual column

Tags: python, json, api, csv, iterable

I'm trying to take data from Iterable and transfer it to a readable CSV via API call. When I run this line of code to get the "metrics" data, it works just fine. However, when I try to pull the metadata with the same code, the csv file shows all the data in one row with each data point for each campaign in its own individual column. I need the metadata to appear in the csv in the same way that the metrics does, so that I can collapse both datasets together via campaign ID and eventually run regressions.

Code that works:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader
import os
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
thirty_days_ago = int((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8)).timestamp() * 1000)
headers = {
    'Api_Key': '"API KEY"',
}
r1 = requests.get('https://api.iterable.com/api/campaigns', headers=headers)
x1 = r1.json()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1['campaigns'])
df1['createdAt'] = df1['createdAt'].astype(str).astype(int)
df2 = df1[df1['createdAt'] > thirty_days_ago]
id1 = pd.DataFrame(df2['id'])
id2 = '&campaignId=' + id1.astype(str)
id3 = id2.to_string(index=False,header=False)
id4 = id3.replace(" ", "")
id5 = id4.replace("\n", "")
id6 = (id5[1:])
r2 = requests.get("https://api.iterable.com/api/campaigns/metrics?{}".format(id5), headers=headers)
with open('/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryMetrics.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r2.text)
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryMetrics.txt")
dataframe1["_sdc_batched_at"] = pd.Timestamp(datetime.now())
dataframe1.to_csv('/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryMetrics.csv',index = None)'
```

Code that does not work:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader
import os
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
thirty_days_ago = int((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=8)).timestamp() * 1000)
headers = {
    'Api_Key': '"API KEY"',
}
r1 = requests.get('https://api.iterable.com/api/campaigns', headers=headers)
x1 = r1.json()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1['campaigns'])
df1['createdAt'] = df1['createdAt'].astype(str).astype(int)
df2 = df1[df1['createdAt'] > thirty_days_ago]
id1 = pd.DataFrame(df2['id'])
id2 = '&campaignId=' + id1.astype(str)
id3 = id2.to_string(index=False,header=False)
id4 = id3.replace(" ", "")
id5 = id4.replace("\n", "")
id6 = (id5[1:])
r2 = requests.get("https://api.iterable.com/api/campaigns".format(id5), headers=headers)
with open('/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryLabels.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r2.text)
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryLabels.txt")
dataframe1["_sdc_batched_at"] = pd.Timestamp(datetime.now())
dataframe1.to_csv('/Users/ml/Documents/Data/HickoryLabels.csv',index = None)
```

[image: CSV files]

Comment: This line `r2 = requests.get("https://api.iterable.com/api/campaigns".format(id5), headers=headers)` is wrong at least because you say you want to use `id5` somewhere in the URL, but you haven't supplied `{}` in the URL. I'm guessing, based on the URL that does work, that you're missing a key part of the API, maybe something like `.../campaigns/metadata?{}`??

Comment: I tried that and I got a ParserError that said "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 2"

Comment: Double-check the API spec for "metadata", compare it to "metrics", and see if they even support what you want to do. Once you know that the API supports the kind of request you want to make, update this question with the specific error message, and the specific script that has the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that (I'm fairly new to python and to API requests), but in that second picture in the original post, it pulled the metadata that I wanted. It just pulled it in a format where there was only one column. I need to import that same data but in a more palpable csv format

Comment: To me, it's clear that you're not getting what you think you're getting. You think you're getting CSV in that second request, but you're actually getting JSON, and I'm pretty sure that's because that line I mentioned in the first comment is not what you want. Stop both programs after you write `r2.text()` to the TXT file and compare the two 'HickoryLabels.txt' files. I believe you'll see they are very different.